# compiling mem.c without CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM flag

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to compile `mem.c` module with a `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` disabled. The idea is to have a module that will allow me to access address space in `/dev/mem` above 1MB. Why? I'm doing some testing which requires access to this memory space.

I copied `mem.c` into my home directory, removed code that has access restriction and compiled it. However I'm getting the following warnings:

```
WARNING: "kmsg_fops" [/home/user/projects/new_mem/mem.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "tty_init" [/home/user/projects/new_mem/mem.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "phys_mem_access_prot" [/home/user/projects/new_mem/mem.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "xlate_dev_mem_ptr" [/home/user/projects/new_mem/mem.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "devmem_is_allowed" [/home/user/projects/new_mem/mem.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "splice_from_pipe" [/home/user/projects/new_mem/mem.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "shmem_zero_setup" [/home/user/projects/new_mem/mem.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic'
```

My questions are:

Do I really have to compile every module that have these functions defined or there is another way to do it? If there is then what is it?

All I need need is to compile code to be able to access `/dev/mem`, I really don't need all the other modules. Short of removing unnecessary code from `mem.c` is there another way to remove this code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not all of Linux is meant to be run as modules...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you clarify your comment? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `mem.o` is supposed to be linked into the final kernel executable.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Aren't all modules supposed to be linked with the kernel?

Comment: Yes, but not all compilation units can be used as modules.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams As far as I understand `mem.c` is a driver. Aren't drivers supposed to be loadable and unloadable?

Comment: Where did you hear that `mem.c` is a driver?

Comment: The code for it is located under `drivers/char`. I assume that all the drivers are located under a `drivers` directory. Am I wrong?

Comment: Modules are meant to be loadable and unloadable. Not all drivers are modules.